# Post data from one form to another

Tags: php, forms, synology

I have a Synology NAS server with the dynamic IP address. I am not able to change it to the static one at the moment, but I still have a temporary solution for this problem:
To find my NAS I decided to create a PHP variable that will contain an IP address of my router (I will try to do it somehow) and it will transfer the value to the remote server of mine and insert it as the link, like:

```
$current_IP = 1.2.3.4;
$port = 5000;
```

// Post this variables to another page on remote host;

```
echo "<a href='http://$current_IP.$port'>";
```

The form is located on that remote server and after user clicks 'Login', all the data from the form (username&pass) will be posted to the form located under the `http://1.2.3.4:5000` and submitted under it.

So, the question is: how to post all the data from one form to another one and automatically submit them?

P.S. I have the two-factor authentication enabled, so in the default page a user will be redirected to another page with a single input field to enter that 6-digit code. But this is not a problem form me.

Comment: What is the ultimate goal? Just bypassing the problem of having a dynamic ip?

Comment: Yes. And to export the login page to another one with custom styling and other pages.

Comment: @ArtemUshakov Consult my answer below, if that is the desired goal.

Comment: @ArtemUshakov Ok not a problem. You will however need to change `$current_IP = 1.2.3.4;` to this `$current_IP = "1.2.3.4";` otherwise, it will create an error. Btw, I deleted my answer.

Comment: In addition the link looks off, port numbers are preceded by a colon `:` not period `.`